# what happens to light energy when it is stored in a prism with angleA > angle R

Tags: reflection

In a glass prism if any light is incident for which angle of prism is twice the critical angle than it does not escape prism.Does it mean it has become like a black hole which eats away all visible incident light?

With so much light energy stored, can it explode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it would have to be the case on the 3 side of the prism for the light get trap.

Second, nothing is 100% transparent so the glass would finally absorb the light.

Third, when an object is black the incoming light is trapped as well. And the object don't explode :-)
When energy is absorbed, temperature rise. But when temperature rise, it escapes the object by thermal radiation and thermal conduction (with everything in contact) so that a balance is reached.

Comment: can we store some energy in this way and use it for some other work?

Comment: yes: the best way to extract energy from Sun is to paint water pipes in black and produce hot water this way. Prism is just a costlier, more complicated and less efficient way of doing it. ;-)